# What "Did I do this" refers to?

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

> There was an unearthly quality to the atmosphere inside the Frieze New York art fair, like the air in a plane—still but pressurized, with an unsettling hum—when the fiction writer Ottessa Moshfegh visited to speak about her work one afternoon in May. “I hate this fair already,” she said when she walked in, handing her ticket to a very tall, very pale man dressed entirely in black lace. Almost immediately, she was lost in the labyrinth of works for sale: Takashi Murakami’s lurid blond plastic milkmaids with long legs and erect nipples; the words “any messages?” spelled out in neon tubing. It was like an enactment of the world inhabited by the protagonist of Moshfegh’s forthcoming novel, “My Year of Rest and Relaxation,” who works at a gallery in Chelsea, amid objects like a quarter-million-dollar “pair of toy monkeys made using human pubic hair,” with camera penises poking out from their fur. “**Did I do this?**” Moshfegh said, only half kidding. She sometimes gets the sense that she has the power to conjure reality through her writing.

https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2018/07/09/ottessa-moshfeghs-otherworldly-fiction

When she says “Did I do this?” It is not clear what the text is talking about. I don’t think she was talking about Murakami work. If I want to translate it does not make sense. Of course she is not taking about the art gallery that happened in her forthcoming book.

Comment: This isn't really about meaning of language so much as reading comprehension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question regarding meaning of “spell out”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/191565/question-regarding-meaning-of-spell-out)

Comment: My question is this: Is that clear from the passage what moshfegh was talking about? Is she talking about those Takashi Murakami work? Or some other art work that had not mentioned in the passage?

Comment: @rpeinhardt considering the recommended course of action if you have multiple questions about a passage is to post each as a separate question (the alternative being a humongous wall of questions closed immediately as "too broad") I disagree it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

"Did I do this?" is referring to the fair that Moshfegh is visiting which seems

> like an enactment of the world inhabited by the protagonist of Moshfegh’s forthcoming novel.

This is reinforced by the sentence:

> She sometimes gets the sense that she has the power to conjure reality through her writing